# Split a comma separated strings in Bash

Tags: bash

I have this file with 20k+ IPs inside:

```
104.20.15.220,104.20.61.219,104.20.62.219,104.20.73.221,104.20.74.221,104.20.14.220
104.20.15.220,104.20.73.221,104.20.74.221,104.25.195.107,104.25.196.107,104.20.14.220
91.215.154.209
...
```

The question is how to split in into single IPs on each string:

```
104.20.15.220
104.20.61.219
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just replace a comma with a new line with either of these commands:

```
tr ',' '\n' < file

sed 's/,/\n/g' file

perl 's/,/\n/g' file

awk 'gsub(/,/,"\n")' file
```

... or match every block of text up to a comma or the end of line:

```
grep -oP '.*?(?=,|$)' file
```

... or loop through the fields and print them:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

... or set the record separator to the comma and let `awk` do all the work:

```
awk -v RS=, '1' file
awk 1 RS=, file
```

... or match the IPs, you can use the regex from [Matching IPv4 Addresses](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html):

```
grep -oE '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' file
```

---

They all return:

```
104.20.15.220
104.20.61.219
104.20.62.219
104.20.73.221
...
```

Comment: If you wanna make it even shorter, you can go for `awk 1 RS=, file`

Comment: could add few more ways: `grep -oP '.*?(?=,|$)'` , `grep -oP '(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'` , `perl -pe 's/,/\n/g'` etc as well :)

Comment: `awk 'gsub(/,/,"\n")' file`

Comment: `tr`, `sed`, `awk`, `grep` everything covered in one answer +1

Comment: Wait? Where's `echo`? :D

Comment: @JamesBrown `while IFS= read -r -d$',' line; do echo "$line"; done < file`? ;-D

Answer (score 2):

This will transform all the commands into newline.

```
tr ',' '\n' <filename
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\n"}{$1=$1}1' filename
```