# Why is `awk 1 RS=, <<< "1,2"` writing an extra new line?

Tags: awk, gawk

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39528355/1983854) a question in which I used a little `awk` trick to convert commas into new lines:

```
awk 1 RS=, file
```

However, I then noticed that this is introducing an extra new line to the end of the output:

```
$ cat a
1,2
$ awk 1 RS=, a
1
2
             # one extra line
$ awk 1 RS=, <<< "1,2"
1
2
             # one extra line
```

Since `1` is short-hand for `{print $0}` I decided to see what is going on:

```
$ awk '{print $0, "hey"}' RS=, <<< "1,2"
1 hey
2
 hey
```

So yes, apparently the splitting is done, but for some reason the second record consists in `2` followed by a new line. And yes, `awk` just sees two records:

```
$ awk '{print NR}' RS=, <<< "1,2"
1
2
```

To me this made sense, since `echo` and here-strings add such new line to the end of their output, while `printf` does not. And effectively it works fine with *printf*:

```
$ awk '{print $0, "hey"}' RS=, < <(printf "1,2")
1 hey
2 hey         # no more lines after this
```

OK, I said: then it is just a problem on the new line that gets appended to the end of the string.

But then... I see that it is not always the case and my confusion gets bigger:

```
$ awk '{print $0, "hey"}' <<< "1,2"
1,2 hey         # no more lines after this
```

So my question is: **what is `RS=,` doing to cause this extra new line to be appended?**

Comment: are you confusing the record separator with the field separator?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk processes each record, automatically removing the record separator from the end. If you've changed it to something other than a newline, this means that it won't be removed, so you end up with this behaviour.

Your "record count" is 2 even though you only have one `,` but it's also 2 in this example (which hopefully doesn't make this even more confusing!):

```
$ printf 'a\nb' | awk '{print NR}'
1
2
```

Comment: OOOOK so the key here is the removal of the `RS`: when it is not a new line, `1,2\n` gets treated as this, so `awk` sees 1st record being `1` and 2nd record being `2\n`.

Answer (score 2):

it's the newline in the input stream.

```
$ awk 1 RS=, < <(echo -n 1,2)

1
2
```

won't have the extra newline in the output.  However, the standard way to do this is with `tr`

```
$ tr ',' '\n' < file
```

compare

```
$ echo 1,2 | awk 1 RS=,
1
2

$ echo 1,2 | tr ',' '\n'
1
2
```

Comment: But why is this happening when using `RS=,` and not when it is the default?

Comment: when you set RS to comma, it leaves the last newline in place as part of the record.  Whether the last newline is required in the input file before EOF is a bigger debate.

Comment: Very good point, now I get it. In fact this remains me about a question I myself asked a while ago: [Trailing new line after piping to a command: is there any standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36641445/1983854)

Answer (score 2):

It's not awk that's adding a newline, it's `<<<`. If the shell didn't add a terminating newline to the end of the text you specify using `<<<` then the result would not be a text "file" per POSIX and so would rely on undefined behavior from any tool trying to parse it.

So when you write `command <<< 'foo'` what `command` sees is not `foo`, it's `foo\n` and therefore in your command line:

```
awk 1 RS=, <<< "1,2"
```

what awk sees is `1,2\n` and when you split that into records at the `,` you get the first record of `1` and the 2nd record of `2\n`.